# How do I efficiently add existentially typed safe money values?

Tags: haskell, currency, dependent-type, existential-type

I wrote a toy library that uses dependent types to represent money with its currency in the type signature:

```hs
data Currency = CHF | EUR | PLN | USD
  deriving stock (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Read, Show)

data CurrencyWitness (c :: Currency) where
  CHFWitness :: CurrencyWitness CHF
  EURWitness :: CurrencyWitness EUR
  PLNWitness :: CurrencyWitness PLN
  USDWitness :: CurrencyWitness USD

deriving stock instance Eq (CurrencyWitness c)
deriving stock instance Show (CurrencyWitness c)


data Money (currency :: Currency) representation = Money
  { moneyCurrency :: !(CurrencyWitness currency)
  , moneyAmount :: !representation
  }
  deriving stock (Eq, Show)

add :: (Num r) => Money c r -> Money c r -> Money c r
add (Money witness1 amount1) (Money _ amount2) =
  Money witness1 (amount1 + amount2)

data SomeMoney r where
  SomeMoney :: Money c r -> SomeMoney r
```

How can I now write `addSomeMoney :: (Num r) => SomeMoney r -> SomeMoney r -> Maybe (SomeMoney r)` that safely adds money only if they are of the same currency? You can imagine that this might be needed in a situation where users provide money arguments, so we can't check their currency at compile time.

My best approach is:

```hs
addSomeMoney (SomeMoney m@(Money c _)) (SomeMoney m'@(Money c' _)) = case (c, c') of
  (CHFWitness, CHFWitness) -> Just . SomeMoney $ add m m'
  (PLNWitness, PLNWitness) -> Just . SomeMoney $ add m m'
  -- ...
  (_, _) -> Nothing
```

This approach has the drawback that it is cumbersome to write, repetitive, and becomes faulty when I add a new currency as the compiler won't warn me that that case is not handled.

```hs
addSomeMoney (SomeMoney m@(Money c _)) (SomeMoney m'@(Money c _)) = _
```

doesn't work. GHC complains about duplicate `c`: `Conlicting definitions of 'c'`.

Comment: I'm not really following what the `CurrencyWitness` is doing? What does it "more" than the `Currency` itself?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem ad-hoc [singleton](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-3.0.2/docs/Data-Singletons.html#t:Sing) type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A completely "type safe" approach is possible, but we have to write some boilerplate.

We start from the OP's code, mostly verbatim. We only add a few extensions, enable warnings (which should more properly be done elsewhere, but let's keep this simply) and `import Data.Typeable`.

(I haven't checked if some extensions can be removed)

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DerivingStrategies, KindSignatures,
    StandaloneDeriving, DataKinds, RankNTypes, 
    TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}
   
import Data.Typeable

data Currency = CHF | EUR | PLN | USD
  deriving stock (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Read, Show)

data CurrencyWitness (c :: Currency) where
  CHFWitness :: CurrencyWitness 'CHF
  EURWitness :: CurrencyWitness 'EUR
  PLNWitness :: CurrencyWitness 'PLN
  USDWitness :: CurrencyWitness 'USD

deriving stock instance Eq (CurrencyWitness c)
deriving stock instance Show (CurrencyWitness c)

data Money (currency :: Currency) representation = Money
  { moneyCurrency :: !(CurrencyWitness currency)
  , moneyAmount :: !representation
  }
  deriving stock (Eq, Show)

add :: (Num r) => Money c r -> Money c r -> Money c r
add (Money witness1 amount1) (Money _ amount2) =
  Money witness1 (amount1 + amount2)

data SomeMoney r where
  SomeMoney :: Money c r -> SomeMoney r
```

Now the new part.

We first "prove" that any currency type `c` satisfies the `Typeable` constraint. This is trivial to do, but requires some boilerplate.

Importantly, adding new currencies will trigger a non-exhaustive patter matching warning, so it is reasonably easy to keep it in sync.

```
withTypeableCurrency :: CurrencyWitness c -> (Typeable c => a) -> a
withTypeableCurrency CHFWitness x = x
withTypeableCurrency EURWitness x = x
withTypeableCurrency PLNWitness x = x
withTypeableCurrency USDWitness x = x
```

Then, the currency-adding function. We invoke `withTypeableCurrency` to put two `Typeable` constraints in scope. Then we leverage `eqT` to check if the two currency types are the same. In the affirmative case, we do not get a boring `True` boolean, but a convenient `Refl` which allows the compiler to identify the types. The rest is then easy.

```
addSomeMoney :: (Num r) => SomeMoney r -> SomeMoney r -> Maybe (SomeMoney r)
addSomeMoney (SomeMoney (m1@(Money (c1 :: CurrencyWitness tc1) _)))
             (SomeMoney (m2@(Money (c2 :: CurrencyWitness tc2) _))) =
  withTypeableCurrency c1 $
  withTypeableCurrency c2 $
  case eqT @tc1 @tc2 of
    Just Refl -> Just . SomeMoney $ add m1 m2
    Nothing   -> Nothing  -- not the same type of currency
```

The advantage of this approach is that the boilerplate is confined within `withTypeableCurrency`, and does not have to be repeated in each function dealing with `SomeMoney` like `addSomeMoney`, `subtractSomeMoney`, etc.

---

Update: some of the boilerplate can be removed exploiting the `singletons` package and some Template Haskell.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DerivingStrategies, KindSignatures,
    StandaloneDeriving, DataKinds, RankNTypes, TypeApplications,
    ScopedTypeVariables, TemplateHaskell, EmptyCase, TypeFamilies,
    UndecidableInstances, TypeSynonymInstances, InstanceSigs #-}

import Data.Singletons.Decide
import Data.Singletons.TH

$(singletons [d|
  data Currency = CHF | EUR | PLN | USD
    deriving (Eq, Read, Show, Bounded)
  |])
-- This automatically creates the equivalent of
--    data SCurrency :: Currency -> Type where
--       SCHF :: SCurrency 'CHF
--       SEUR :: SCurrency 'EUR
--       SPLN :: SCurrency 'PLN
--       SUSD :: SCurrency 'USD
-- and some helper stuff.

-- singletons does not like deriving Enum, so we move it here.
deriving stock instance Enum Currency

-- singletons does not create this for some reason.
deriving stock instance Eq (SCurrency c)

data Money (currency :: Currency) representation = Money
  { moneyCurrency :: !(SCurrency currency)
  , moneyAmount :: !representation
  }
  deriving stock (Eq, Show)

add :: (Num r) => Money c r -> Money c r -> Money c r
add (Money witness1 amount1) (Money _ amount2) =
  Money witness1 (amount1 + amount2)

data SomeMoney r where
  SomeMoney :: Money c r -> SomeMoney r
```

The key function is even simpler, exploiting `%~`.

```
addSomeMoney :: (Num r) => SomeMoney r -> SomeMoney r -> Maybe (SomeMoney r)
addSomeMoney (SomeMoney m1@(Money c1 _))
             (SomeMoney m2@(Money c2 _)) =
  -- Check for singleton equality.
  case c1 %~ c2 of
    Proved    Refl -> Just . SomeMoney $ add m1 m2
    Disproved _    -> Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to write a function that [demotes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-3.0.2/docs/Data-Singletons.html#t:Demote) the singletons back to normal values:

```
demoteCurrencyWitness :: CurrencyWitness c -> Currency
demoteCurrencyWitness CHFWitness = CHF
...
```

Then you can use a bog-standard equality check, and a currency-oblivious addition:

```
addSomeMoney (SomeMoney (Money c amount)) (SomeMoney (Money c' amount'))
 | demoteCurrencyWitness c == demoteCurrencyWitness c'
              = Just . SomeMoney . Money c $ amount+amount'
 | otherwise  = Nothing
```

In this case, a forgotten clause for `demoteCurrencyWitness` would give a clear error instead of wrong `Nothing` result.

It's still kind of tedious having to write this, so I'd use [`singletons-th`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons-th) instead.

Comment: That solves the most pressing problems of repetitivness and fragility, thank you. One drawback is that it unfortunately relies on "cheating" the type system by avoiding the type-safe `add` function. There would be no warnings if we replaced `==` with `/=`. A solution that also prevents that would be perfect.

Comment: I don't think there's a good way to get rid of the equality check completely, but you could encapsulate it: generalise the addition to a `liftA2`-like operator `withSameCurrency` on `SomeMoney`, such that `addSomeMoney = withSameCurrency (+)`.